# What type of plant is this? It looks like Chamomile

Tags: identification, flowers

I'm thinking it could be Chamomile, but I'm not quite sure. This was found in Washington. Any ideas?

[image: ???]

Comment: I'm guessing you mean Washington state not the city of Washington DC?

Answer (score 11):

Pacific Northwest, it's either Mayweed Chamomile, or Pineapple Chamomile, both members of the fennel family.

As kids, we'd pull the flower heads off and chew on them for the flavor. We grew up with the Mayweed variety.

[OSU Identification - Mayweed & Mountain Pineapple](http://oregonstate.edu/dept/nursery-weeds/feature_articles/mayweed_pineapple/anthemis_cotula_vs_matricaria_matricarioidies.html)

Comment: That explains the pineapple taste. Thank you!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matricaria_discoidea

Comment: Ah, then you have the other variety that grows here. Must be in more mountainous country or rocky areas. The Mayweed variety is more of a grasslands inhabitant.

Comment: Definitely pineapple-weed as @Siv linked! Called such because it smells a bit like pineapple when crushed. It's delicious when [brewed as a tisane](http://montanahomesteader.com/pineapple-weed-tea/): pick a bunch of the flower-heads, then brew with boiling water for 5+ mins (e.g., like chamomile). You can also dry them for later use.

Answer (score 6):

Your picture is blurred but looks like *Chamaemelum nobile* (L.) All. from *Asteraceae* family. It can grow on poor soils and the flowering time is between june and july (maybe september on cold places) on the northen hemisphere.  If your picture was taken recently... you have a positive match!

References:

[*Chamaemelum nobile* (L.) All.](http://www.botanicayjardines.com/chamaemelum-nobile/) (Spanish)

[*Chamaemelum nobile* (L.) All.](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?kempercode=b144)